# Richtext enabled software that can save in a markdown

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, conversion, website, markdown

How can I copy text from a webpage (ex. [this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-headers-and-footers-HP001226486.aspx#BM6)) and use it to answer a question on [SuperUser](http://Superuser.com) while retaining formatting?

What software can act as an intermediary to convert a document (MS word recognizes the bolded text), to a markdown copyable format?

Comment: http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/

Comment: @slhck Thanks, It worked, so its the answer.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @slhck How about something for webpages like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202164)

Comment: @slhck Are there any that aren't on a blog?  Blogs aren't accessable from my school.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't completly answer the question, using the [site](http://aaronsw.com/2002/html2text) [shlck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) suggested works for webpages (it doesn't let you upload files for conversion...)