# How can I remove all bookmarks from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I accidentally set up both delicious bookmark sync and chrome data sync, so now around 4000 bookmarks from delicious have been imported into my Google account that is synced with Google Chrome.

I'd like to remove these from my Google account so they are not all being synced. What is the best way to do this?

**note**

I want to keep syncing, and keep other synced data, but just delete bookmarks. I don't want to delete the bookmarks just from the browser, I want them out of Google's storage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delicious stores their bookmarks inside folders. Simply disable the extension, open the Bookmark manager, and delete all the folders that say "Delicious - do not delete"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to remove these from my google account so they are not all being synced. What is the best way to do this?

## Delete synced data from your Google Account

You can delete your synced data from your Google Account at any time, using
the [Google Dashboard](http://www.google.com/dashboard).

1. Click the wrench icon [image: wrench icon] on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Options** (**Preferences** on Mac or Linux).
3. Click the **Personal Stuff** tab.
4. In the "Sync" section, click **Remove synced data on Google Dashboard**.
5. Go to the “Chrome sync” section in the dashboard and click **Stop sync and delete data from Google**.

Sync will be disabled and all the sync data that has been saved to your Google
Account will be deleted (but not from your computer). That means information
like your bookmarks, apps, and extensions on your current computer won’t show
up if you enable sync on another computer.

---

*Some additional information about syncing data with your Google account.*

### Enabling or disabling sync

You can enable [sync](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=165139) on as many computers as you'd like and across different operating systems. Make sure you enable sync on ***each*** computer that should share the same Google Chrome settings. Follow
these steps:

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click the wrench icon [image: wrench icon] on the browser toolbar.
3. Select **Options** (**Preferences** on Mac and Linux).
4. Click the **Personal Stuff** tab.
5. In the "Sync" section, click **Set up sync**.
6. Sign in to your Google Account in the dialog that appears.
7. In the "Confirm Sync Preferences" dialog that appears, choose what you want to sync.

   - **Sync everything**: Click "OK, sync everything" button.
   - **Choose specific items to sync**: Click "Advanced" and select "Choose what to sync" from the drop down menu. Select the checkboxes for the items you want to sync.

     - [Apps](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1050586) from the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore)
     - [Autofill](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142464) (except for credit card numbers)
     - [Bookmarks](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95739)
     - [Extensions](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=154007) from the Chrome Web Store (except those containing plug-ins)
     - [Passwords](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95606)
     - Preferences
     - [Themes](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=148695)
   - **Deselect bookmarks to stop syncing bookmarks**
8. Click **OK**.

You can visit the Google Chrome Support Article in its entirety [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185277).

Comment: I want to keep syncing, and keep other synced data, but just delete bookmarks. i don't want to delete the bookmarks just from the browser, i want them out of google's storage...

Comment: I edited my answer (bottom half, number 7).  Does that help?

Comment: am i missing a way to delete all of them out of my google account?

Comment: Read the beginning part of my answer

Comment: I did. looks like your answer shows how to remove them out of the browser but leaves them in the google account. am i missing that part?

Comment: You deleted the data from your dashboard?

Comment: @AnwarShah: Thanks for the comp.  Google really helped, along with [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/356021/81403).

Answer (score -1):

Try backing up and deleting the `Bookmarks` file in your Chrome profile:

**Windows 7:**

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

**Windows XP:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[USERNAME]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Comment: hmm, wouldn't sync just put them back again when i run chrome?

Comment: @cwd: It did recreate the `Bokmarks` file for me within seconds..